# Getting “scp: Target is not a directory” when trying to upload files from desktop to a remote Unix directory

Tags: mac, unix, upload, linux-terminal

I’m trying to upload a file from my desktop to `directory2/` on my university's Unix server. I tried doing this:

```
scp /Macintosh HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2
```

I’m getting this message when I do the above command:

> scp: Target is not a directory, but more files selected for upload

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? What’s the correct way to upload these files?

Comment: There are *two* reasons for this, probably, but can you check `ssh myusername@server.name.ca "ls -ld /directory1/directory2"` first?

Comment: Are you literally typing in `scp /Macintosh HD/` because that space needs to be escaped like this: `scp /Macintosh\ HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2` or enclose the macOS path in quotes like this: `scp "/Macintosh HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c" myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comment you try to copy one directory and one file to remote server. Command:

```
scp /Macintosh HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2
```

try to copy `/Macintosh` and `HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c` to remote. If this is you intention you should enter command like

```
scp /Macintosh HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2/
```

(see backslash at the end)
if you want to copy only C file you should use command like:

```
scp "/Macintosh HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c" myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2
```

or

```
scp /Macintosh\ HD/Users/myname/Desktop/filename.c myusername@server.name.ca:/directory1/directory2
```